# Gwt + Maven + Idea, Project Compiler Output setting

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea, settings

I've created gwt project using maven plugin:

```
mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.1 -DgroupId=com.savdev.BasicGwtProject -DartifactId=BasicGwtProject -Dversion=1.0 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:generate
```

Then I created a new IDEA projext using the generated pom.xml file. At the moment Project Compiler Output folder points to `PrjectName/out`, as usual I set it to ProjectName/target folder, to build project both with maven and IDEA, but when I ran maven install I haven't found class folder in the ProjectName/target directory. Where does the "Project Compiler Output" should point when mix IDEA, Maven for GWT project.

Comment: Please mention which IDEA edition you are using version/community edition/licensed etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Project Compiler Output' is used as a base directory for output paths for modules when IDEA project structure is created by hand. If a project is imported from Maven IDEA set output paths for modules individually accordingly to Maven configuration (see 'Paths' tab of a module editor in 'Project Structure' dialog) and 'Project Compiler Output' isn't used at all.